# ERROR on page in NAVISION

Tags: dynamics-nav

Good morning, I have a problem when running a page that believes in NAV. On the page I am using an OCX called MSCOMM32.OCX compile my code and it does not mark me error but when I want to see the functionality I run the page and it sends me the following error.

[image]

I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: the COM class generator can not be recovered for the component with CLSID{648A.....

Comment: have you tried to (re)register the ocx?

Comment: Were you running the Windows Client on the same server as the Development Client?